# TypeScript - Check if Object has all values within an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to filter an object that only returns if the property has all the values within the filtered array. This is the code:

```
    const getFilteredProducts = ()=>{
        const filterBrands:string[] = [];
        const filterGender:string[] = [];

        FilterState().brand.map(brand =>{
            if(brand.checked == true){
                filterBrands.push(brand.brand);
            }
        });
        FilterState().gender.map(brand =>{
            if(brand.checked == true){
                filterGender.push(brand.gender);
            }
        })
        products?.map((product)=>{
            if(Object.values(product.Brand).includes(filterBrands[0]) && Object.values(product.Gender).includes(filterGender[0])){
                console.log(product);
            }

        })
    }
```

I am firstly looping through the Brand filter and if the filter is ticked it adds it to the brand filter array. E.g- Nike is tick so Nike is added to the filter array. Then I do the same with the gender filter
Then I am looping through the object and I want to check if the object has the brand name that within the array and same with the gender. How can I change the `includes(filterBrands[0])`  to something that checks all the array? If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayContainsArray(superset, subset) {
  return subset.every((value) => superset.includes(value));
}

const getFilteredProducts = () => {
  const filterBrands = FilterState()
                          .brand.filter((brand) => brand.checked === true)
                          .map((brand) => brand.brand);

  const filterGender = FilterState()
                          .gender.filter((gender) => gender.checked === true)
                          .map((gender) => gender.gender);

  const result = products.filter((product) => arrayContainsArray(Object.values(product.Brand), filterBrands) && arrayContainsArray(Object.values(product.Gender), filterGender));

  for (const p of result) {
    console.log(p);
  }
};
```